# Nb/Poisson regression with weighted survey data resulting in counts with decimals

Tags: poisson-regression, negative-binomial-distribution, survey-weights

I am analysing suicide counts and thus it seems appropriate to use Nb/Poisson regression. However, my counts come from survey data and are only whole numbers when unweighted. Once I realise the weights (which include decimals) the counts contain decimals, and I believe Nb/Poisson models require whole numbers to properly compute. Would the only solution to this problem be to round off the weighted counts? Is it perhaps better to explore using OLS regression instead in this case?

Edit:

I could not find a way to use the survey package because I have to first aggregate the data into counts before modelling, but the weighting variables only exist at the raw data level. Thus I just used the "wt" argument when creating the counts.

The raw data looks like this (first four variables are related to weighting):

```
 mortuary_code sampling_strata   fpc weighting Province     Suicide_Mechanism Date_of_Death Month Day_of_Week Sex     Age
          <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>        <chr>                     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <chr> <dbl>
1             1               2    33      4.41 Eastern Cape Sharp force               40075     9 Saturday    male     41
2             1               2    33      4.41 Eastern Cape Hanging                   39983     6 Friday      male     68
3             1               2    33      4.41 Eastern Cape Ingestion                 40028     8 Monday      male     30
4             1               2    33      4.41 Eastern Cape Ingestion                 40115    10 Thursday    male     32
5             1               2    33      4.41 Eastern Cape Hanging                   39980     6 Tuesday     male     18
6             1               2    33      4.41 Eastern Cape Hanging                   39948     5 Friday      male     50
```

I use the following code to create counts:

```
data = main_dataset %>% count(Sex, Age_Group, IMSyear, wt=weighting)
```

The new count-based dataframe looks like this (population and Suicide_rate added separately after):

```
Sex    Age_Group IMSyear     n population Suicide_rate
  <chr>  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
1 female 0-14         2009  39.9    7186279        0.555
2 female 0-14         2017  50.9    7924168        0.642
3 female 0-14         2021  74.5    8149386        0.914
4 female 15-24        2009 398.     5131260        7.76 
5 female 15-24        2017 312.     4762566        6.56 
6 female 15-24        2021 383.     4698113        8.14
```

Thus the issue is that "n" ends up including decimal places after using the "wt" argument. The weights are obviously very important because without them the sampling isn't representative.

My model ends up looking something like this:

```
model = glm.nb(n ~ IMSyear+Age_Group+Sex+offset(log(population)), control = glm.control(maxit = 100), data = data)
```

R doesn't mind fitting the model, it just gives warnings and then rounds to nearest integer from what I can tell. So ultimately my question is whether there is a better way to do things or if I should be satisfied with that.

Comment: do a count regression using the original counts, and specify the weights as a separate argument. For example, in R, the argument is called "weights": https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html

Comment: What @JohnMadden said, except if it comes from survey data, I recommend the R `{survey}` package. You specify the weights in a `svydesign` object, then fit a `svyglm` with a Poisson family, which accounts for the weights. The `weights` argument in base `glm` is not for survey weights.

Comment: Thanks both! @AlexJ the reason I've not used the survey package is that my raw dataset is just individual suicide instances so I've had to use `count` to create counts. The problem then is that I only have weights for rows of the raw dataset, not the aggregated data counts. It's easy to add weights when implementing the aggregation so that's the route I've gone. Not sure if the survey package allows me to create a svydesign object that still applies to subsequent counts I create?

Comment: Hmmmm. Not sure at this stage. Could you update the question with some example data (anonymised etc as necessary) and also a little bit on the survey design,

Comment: Thanks again. Have edited the post with examples of the raw dataset and the count dataset to demonstrate. Let me know if you need any other info to be able to help. I appreciate your comments very much.

Comment: Hi, sorry this slipped off my radar. If you still need assistance - Can you tell me about what kind of survey (eg stratification variable is blah, PSU is blah, simple random etc.)

Comment: No problem, thanks for coming back to it. I am still working on it, though as of now my solution is simply to round to nearest integer and then consider other rounding methods later as potential sensitivity analyses. 

In the raw data above, mortuaries are used as PSU, stratification variable is sampling_strata. I am not sure if fpc was actually used in determining the weights as it's not mentioned in the report that the data comes from. Weight calculations were based on the number+size of mortuaries randomly selected in each stratum of the total number of facilities in each province.